# MySQL How to select and build a set from that select?

Tags: mysql

How can I do something like this with MYSQL?

```
user_id  user_group_id   is_primary
1        2               1
1        3               0
1        4               0
2        2               0
2        3               1
3        2               0
3        3               1
```

Into something like

```
user_id   user_group_ids
1         3,4
2         2
3         2
```

basically the statement would be like this....

```
SELECT user_id, user_group_ids FROM tablename WHERE is_primary = 0
```

Thus i'm only trying to get the SET that isn't primary and build a SET from that.  I want to do this with a SELECT statement.  That select statement that allows me to BUILD the user_group_ids will be used to set the user_group_ids record in another table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(user_group_id) as user_group_id
FROM mytable
WHERE is_primary = 0
GROUP BY user_id
```

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2855/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT user_id, group_concat(user_group_ids) as user_group_ids 
FROM tablename 
WHERE is_primary = 0 
GROUP BY user_id
```

this will group user_group_ids together by user_id